# Using .NET to schedule a task on Azure Scheduler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, scheduler

I am using Azure WebJobs to clean records from my database 48 hours after I have added them. The WebJob is always listening onto a message queue (also on Azure) which will contain a message that specifies which record to delete.

I add record to the DB though my C# MVC application. I wish to use the Azure scheduler to push a message onto the Queue 48 hours after I have added the record. I can't seem to find a way how to schedule these tasks automatically through my MVC. 
Is this possible ? 
I have found ways to call an already configured scheduled job , but I need to create these jobs when I add  the records, so that record specific information is passed to the scheduler body.

Comment: you can use scheduler REST API to create jobs programmatically..[Check this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn528946.aspx)

Comment: @shwetaOnStack:i have created one demo as specified on this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/scheduler-get-started-portal/.But how do i know whether this task has run or not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I add record to the DB though my C# MVC application. I wish to use the
>   Azure scheduler to push a message onto the Queue 48 hours after I have
>   added the record.

One way to achieve this is to immediately push the message in the queue but keep it invisible for 48 hours through a property called [`initialVisibilityDelay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.addmessage.aspx) when adding message to a queue. Will that be an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 1):

Other option would be that instead of doing an continuously WebJob listening to a queue, it could be a WebJob in scheduled mode, checking for items for example in Azure Table Storage if there some jobs to do and if those jobs are 48 hours old.

Answer (score 1):

You can create these jobs using Azure Management Libraries .NET as mentioned here http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2013/12/16/use-windows-azure-scheduler-through-.net-sdk.aspx